# Obtain url get variables when htaccess is already creating a query string

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, get

I have a rule in `.htaccess` that generates a query string according to the url syntax:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule a_([0-9]+)_(.*).html$ article.php?id=$1 [L]
```

So a url like this:

`a_52_how-to-use-htaccess.html` generates: `article.php?id=52`

My question is how to allow htaccess to add to the query string other get variables sent on the url:

```
a_52_how-to-use-htaccess.html?debug=true
```

in order to have:

```
article.php?id=52&debug=true
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `QSA` flag:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule a_([0-9]+)_(.*)\.html$ article.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

- `QSA` (Query String Append) flag preserves existing query parameters while adding a new one.